# Flatlist ScrollToEnd does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How is it possible to to scroll to the bottom of a flatlist when the data is fully loaded.

i thought it should be possible by calling

this._flatList.scrollToEnd() in the componentDidMount function.
This doesn work for me.

If i use that code for a button, then it works.

Then i thought that the onLayout={() => { console.log("onLayout"); this._flatList.scrollToEnd()} } could help. but also this doesnt.

Comment: try call scrollToEnd in setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with timer

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this._flatList.scrollToEnd();
  }, 200);
}
```